# react native encrypt a video file after downloading for in-app use

Tags: android, react-native

I am working on a video downloader app in react native. I am using `rn-fetch-blob` to download a video file inside the storage. I want to encrypt the video file after downloading and decrypt the same video file for playing offline inside my app like Netflix, Youtube, and Hotstar. How to encrypt a video file after downloading or any other approach for video downloading or video encryption?

Comment: Have you looked at react-native-aes ?

Comment: yes, but didn't get the required result.

Comment: Ok let me try later today

Comment: @niklasbec any update? Did you try?